# JavaScript array push not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I am trying to push a value into an array and it is giving me this error in the developer tools.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Here is the code that it seems to be sticking on, word and local word were defined earlier like this.

```
var word = [];
var localWord = []; 

function setLocalArray() {
    // first get words from text field and update word array.
    word = document.getElementById("words").value.split(',');

    // store word array in localStorage            
    for(var i=0; word.length > i; i++) {
        var key2 = "part"+i;
        localStorage.setItem(key2,word[i]);
        localWord.push(key2);
    }

    localStorage.setItem("localWord",JSON.stringify(localWord));
    text2Array();
    reveal();
}
```

localWord.push(key2); Seems to be what it is getting stuck on. I have looked at everything I can find on the push method and I can't seem to find why it is giving me this error. Help?

Here is the full code at jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/runningman24/jnLtpb6y/

Comment: `localWord` got changed to `null` somehow. Is there anything, anywhere that reassigns `localWord`?

Comment: whats goin on in text2Array and reveal?

Comment: is the localWord array defined within an onload or document.ready block?

Comment: in javascript don not create global variable like
var word = [];
var localWord = [];
some other function will also able to update it.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you have `localWord = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localWord"))` somewhere in your code and that is why `localWord` is null. Please show us all of the relevant code when you post a question.

Comment: Here is the full code.  Thanks for all the great comments.  http://jsfiddle.net/runningman24/jnLtpb6y/

Comment: Here's another great comment: Try harder to find the problem within *your* code before making a sweeping statement such as "Javascript array push not working" which is almost certainly never going to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, if you look in the jsfiddle I posted I am trying to pull localWord from localStorage even though it doesn't exist and so it sets it to null. Thank you to all for the ideas and contributions.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this...**

```
var localWord = new Array(); //create new array
var word = new Array();

function setLocalArray() {
    word = document.getElementById("words").value.split(',');
    // store word array in localStorage             
    for(var i=0; word.length > i; i++) {
        var key2 = "part"+i;
        localStorage.setItem(key2,word[i]);
        localWord.push(key2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try isolating the scope of your variable using the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html):

```
var arrayManager =  (function () {
        var word = [];
        var localWord = []; 

        function setLocalArray() {
            // first get words from text field and update word array.
            word = document.getElementById("words").value.split(',');

            // store word array in localStorage            
            for(var i=0; word.length > i; i++) {
                var key2 = "part"+i;
                localStorage.setItem(key2,word[i]);
                localWord.push(key2);
            }

            localStorage.setItem("localWord",JSON.stringify(localWord));
            text2Array();
            reveal();
        }

       return {
          setLocalArray:setLocalArray
        } ;
    }());
```

and the from the outside you have to simply call arrayManager.setLocalArray()